# How to resolve Aerospike::Exceptions::Aerospike: Unsupported Server Feature for Ruby Client?

Tags: ruby, aerospike

While I am trying to write into aerospike using ruby client I am getting the following exception:-

### Aerospike::Exceptions::Aerospike: Unsupported Server Feature

Details:-

```
Aerospike version:- 4.3
Client: [Ruby] aerospike - 2.4.0
namespaces: NS1, NS2, NS3
```

### Note: NS2 and NS3 have single-bin true data-in-index true

Code(which causes the exception):-

```
client = Aerospike::Client.new('aerospike:3000')
key = Aerospike::Key.new('NS2', 'set name', 'this is the key')
data = { 'record'  => 1 }
client.put(key, data) # this line raises the exception
Aerospike::Exceptions::Aerospike: Unsupported Server Feature
```

The exception is not raised if I change NS2 in the key to NS1.

Comment: I suspect you are seeing this because you have supplied a bin name to a single-bin namespace. Try { nil => 1 } or { '' => 1}.

Comment: @kporter when I try {'' => 1} it throws the same error. In case of {nil => 1} it throws Aerospike::Exceptions::Parse: bin name `` is not a string.

Comment: Possibly the ruby client doesn't support single-bin yet. I've pinged our client development team to look into this, but I didn't find any documentation for it.

Comment: @kporter Thanks. Kindly let me know the progress

Comment: Are you by any chance also attempting to store the key? (which wouldn't be supported with single bin configuration I believe). But it doesn't seem that you would be doing this based on the shared code... I wouldn't expect this to be a default policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Unsupported Server Feature" error you are getting is because the Ruby client is sending the user key to the server by default, but the Aerospike server does not support storing the user key for the data-in-memory & single-bin setup. You should see an error message like this in your server logs:

```
Sep 13 2018 02:42:20 GMT: WARNING (rw): (rw_utils.c:153) {sbin} can't store key if data-in-memory & single-bin
```

You'll need to disable sending the key as part of the put request by setting the `send_key` write policy setting to `false`:

```
$ bundle exec irb
2.5.0 :001 > require 'aerospike'; include Aerospike;
 => Object
2.5.0 :002 > client = Client.new; key = Key.new('sbin', 'test', 'foo'); nil
 => nil
2.5.0 :003 > client.put(key, Bin.new('', 42), send_key: false)
 => nil
2.5.0 :004 > client.get(key).bins['']
 => 42
```